# How can I insert values from a listusing a modulo variable in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert values from a temporary table into another table based on a modulo.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Drop Table user_password_list;
Create temporary Table messaging_user_password_list
(id Int(5), Password varChar(1000), User varChar(1000), PRIMARY KEY (id));
set @passwordlist =Insert into messaging_user_password_list values (id,'test1', 'fevea'), ('id,test2','ereavef'),(id,'test3','eareave'),(id,'test4','eavear'),(id,'test5','veaewr'),(id,'test1','heahea');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @passwordlist;     
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

SELECT distinct user_name,setting_name,setting_value 
FROM settings_user ,(select @modulo:=1) AS modulo_count
WHERE settings_user.Setting_Name in ('Password','User');
Drop user_password_list;
```

I'm trying to create a temporary table, loop through my own existing table and update my values for all users. It's for storing passwords for an environment where we have more actual users than there are users allowed into the environment so i'm trying to automate the process of updating username and passwords. Obviously there's no update statement yet, but why do I run into a syntax error for the insert statement?

Answer (score 0):

In the assignment to `@password_list`, You need to add quotes around your query, so that mysql will consider it a *string*:

```
set @passwordlist =”Insert into messaging_user_password_list values (id,'test1', 'fevea'), ('id,test2','ereavef'),(id,'test3','eareave'),(id,'test4','eavear'),(id,'test5','veaewr'),(id,'test1','heahea')”;
```

Furthermore, you need to declare the field `id` in that temporary table as `auto_increment` for that query to work as is.

```
create temporary Table messaging_user_password_list (id Int(5) not null auto_increment, Password varChar(1000), User varChar(1000), PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm still a novice when it comes to SQL. I'll update this question once I get closer to working